# Построчная печать в Tkinter.Text()

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как организовать построчный вывод текста в виджете  Tkinter.Text()
Типа, как при загрузке Windows. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, как выводится текст при загрузке Windows. Не обращал на это внимания. А как строки добавлять -- .insert

```
from Tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
t = Text(tk)
t.pack()
t.insert(END, "line1\nline2")
t.insert(END, "\nline3")
```

Comment: Ответ неверен!

for crash_file in list_crash_files:
    screen_Dead.insert(Tkinter.END, crash_file)
    screen_Dead.update()
    time.sleep(0.001)

Comment: BSOD -- это и есть загрузка Windows? (А кроме шуток, что не нравится в ответе?)

Comment: Строки выводятся на экран все сразу, а не по очереди.

Comment: А, ну тады ой...

Comment: @Xyanight: чтобы не всё сразу показывало, запустите основной цикл (`.mainloop()`) и используйте `.after()` вместо `time.sleep()`

Answer (score 0):

Вариация на [ответ @alexlz](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/108643/23044), которая не весь текст сразу показывает:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
try:
    import Tkinter as tkinter
except ImportError: # Python 3
    import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
text = tkinter.Text(root)
text.pack()
text.insert('end', u"строка сразу видна")
root.after(1000, text.insert, 'end', u"\nчерез секунду")
root.after(2000, text.insert, 'end', u"\nчерез две")
root.after(3210, root.destroy) # exit
root.mainloop()
```